# Permissions Navbar (ngxPermissions) - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm creating a permission for two test users ('ADMIN' and 'USER)' in a Angular project using ngx-permissions.
I want to make the ADMIN user see all items in the navbar, as in the image below:
Items only for ADMIN

[image]

And I want the USER user to see only 1 navbar item, as in the image below:

Item only for USER

[image]

I'm using Ngx Permissions to give the permissions, but I don't know how to set only one of the items to USER. I'm only able to put it to see all items or to see none

Navbar.ts:

```js
import { INavData } from '@coreui/angular';

export const navItems: INavData[] = [
  {
    name: 'Dashboard',
    url: 'home',
    iconComponent: { name: 'cil-speedometer' },
    badge: {
      color: 'info',
      text: 'NEW'
    }
  },
  {
    title: true,
    name: 'Reports'
  },
  {
    name: 'Events',
    url: 'events',
    iconComponent: { name: 'cilSpreadsheet' },
  },
  {
    name: 'Control Test',
    url: 'control-test',
    iconComponent: { name: 'cil-chart-pie' }
  },
  {
    name: 'Example 1',
    url: 'example1',
    iconComponent: { name: 'cil-align-left' },
    children:[
      {
      name: 'Devices',
      url: 'devices',
      iconComponent: { name: 'cil-Bell' }
    },
    {
      name: 'Log',
      url: 'log',
      iconComponent: { name: 'cil-List' }
    },
  ]
  },

];
```

default-layout.component.ts :

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Loader } from "@googlemaps/js-api-loader"
import { navItems } from './_nav';
import { NgxPermissionsService } from 'ngx-permissions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './default-layout.component.html',
})
export class DefaultLayoutComponent implements OnInit {

  public navItems = navItems;

  public perfectScrollbarConfig = {
    suppressScrollX: true,
  };

  constructor(private permissionsService: NgxPermissionsService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      const role = ['ADMIN', 'USER'];
      this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(role)
  }
}
```

default-layout.component.html:

```html
....
  <perfect-scrollbar [config]="perfectScrollbarConfig">
    <!--  [perfectScrollbar]="perfectScrollbarConfig"-->
    <c-sidebar-nav *ngxPermissionsOnly="['ADMIN']" [navItems]="navItems" dropdownMode="close"> </c-sidebar-nav>
  </perfect-scrollbar>
  <c-sidebar-toggler
    *ngIf="!sidebar.narrow"
    toggle="unfoldable"
    cSidebarToggle="sidebar"
  ></c-sidebar-toggler>
</c-sidebar>

<!--main-->
<div class="wrapper d-flex flex-column min-vh-100 bg-light dark:bg-transparent">
  <!--app-header-->
  <app-default-header
    class="mb-4 d-print-none header header-sticky"
    position="sticky"
    sidebarId="sidebar"
  >
  </app-default-header>
  <!--app-body-->
  <div class="body flex-grow-1 px-3">
    <c-container breakpoint="lg" class="h-auto">
      <!-- <google-map
      height= "100%"
      width= "100%"
        [center]="center"
        [zoom]="zoom"
        (mapClick)="moveMap($event)"
        (mapMousemove)="move($event)"
      >
      </google-map> -->
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>




      <!-- <div>Latitude: {{ display?.lat }}</div>
      <div>Longitude: {{ display?.lng }}</div>-->
    </c-container>
  </div>
  <!--app footer-->
  <app-default-footer></app-default-footer>
</div>
```

I could only call ADMIN with ngxpermissionsOnly, so he can see all the items in [navItems], but I don't know how to set only one of the items in [navItems] to USER

Comment: can't you create a second reference to your component and only pass the desired nav item like this `<c-sidebar-nav *ngxPermissionsOnly="['USER']" [navItems]="userNavItems" dropdownMode="close"> </c-sidebar-nav>`. This way I think it will render the admin one with all items and the user one with userNavItems. If `ngxPermissions` acts as an `*ngIf`